# Using UNION in MySQL is not properly combining the rows

Tags: mysql, union

I have a patients table (`kid`) and 2 tables to track both their height and weight in medical routine controls (`track_height`, `track_weight`).

- there may be more than 1 measurement per type (height and weight) on a given month.
- some months might have no measurements at all.
- only months that have BOTH measurements (height and weight), should be presented in the results.
- if there are multiple measurements of any type on any given month, they need to be averaged so that, at best, there is only one result per measurement / per month.

This is my current query:

```
(SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(track_height.date_track), '-', LPAD(MONTH(track_height.date_track), 2, 0)) AS date_track, ROUND(AVG(track_height.height), 1) AS height, NULL AS weight
FROM track_height
WHERE track_height.id_kid = 17
GROUP BY YEAR(track_height.date_track), MONTH(track_height.date_track)
ORDER BY track_height.date_track)

UNION

(SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(track_weight.date_track), '-', LPAD(MONTH(track_weight.date_track), 2, 0)) AS date_track, NULL AS height, ROUND(AVG(track_weight.weight), 1) AS weight
FROM track_weight
WHERE track_weight.id_kid = 17
GROUP BY YEAR(track_weight.date_track), MONTH(track_weight.date_track)
ORDER BY track_weight.date_track)

ORDER BY date_track
```

The problem is that it's being presented like this:

[image: incorrect result]

And it should be presented like this:

[image: correct result]

As you can see, there are 2 specific issues that need to be solved:

- The `UNION` statement is not combining the results by date. There must be only one YYYY-MM row with both height and weight averaged values for that month.
- In this case, **February (2023-02)** should not be printed, because we're missing the weight tracking data for that month.

I've set a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d34e6be/1) example, but in case you want to take a look at the schema, here it is:

```
CREATE TABLE kid (
  id_kid int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  date_insert timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  alias varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  birthday date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO kid (id_kid, date_insert, id_user, alias, gender, birthday, avatar) VALUES (17, '2023-10-22 17:19:08', 'Jenny', '2020-09-30');

CREATE TABLE track_height (
  id_track int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  id_kid int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  date_track date NOT NULL,
  height float UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO track_height (id_track, id_kid, date_track, height) VALUES (45, 17, '2023-04-07', 50), (46, 17, '2023-04-30', 52), (101, 17, '2023-01-31', 25), (102, 17, '2023-02-28', 34), (103, 17, '2023-03-31', 48), (104, 17, '2023-03-15', 42), (105, 17, '2023-03-01', 40), (106, 17, '2023-05-17', 55);

CREATE TABLE track_weight (
  id_track int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  id_kid int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  date_track date NOT NULL,
  weight float UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO track_weight (id_track, id_kid, date_track, weight) VALUES (34, 17, '2023-01-09', 9.6), (35, 17, '2023-01-18', 9.9), (36, 17, '2023-01-31', 10.1), (39, 17, '2023-03-07', 10.5), (40, 17, '2023-03-16', 10.6), (41, 17, '2023-04-05', 10.7), (42, 17, '2023-05-04', 11), (43, 17, '2023-05-30', 11.5);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use `JOIN`, not `UNION`, to combine them into the same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do,

```
select date_format(h.date_track, "%Y-%m"), 
round(avg(h.height), 1) as height, 
round(avg(w.weight), 1) as weight
from track_height h inner join track_weight w 
on h.id_kid = w.id_kid and month(h.date_track) = month(w.date_track)
group by month(h.date_track)
order by month(h.date_track);
```

inner join would make sure that only months that are present in both tables are considered.

Is there any reason for you to use 'Union'?

Comment: There was not a particular reason, just that both tables were equally representative (which means no "main" table) -- that's why I used UNION instead of a JOIN statement, but i see you hit the nail on the head, the query throws the exact expected result.

I'm curious about something, though. In my original query, integers numbers remained without decimals after applying ROUND(AVG(), 1)... but on your proposed solution, 25 becomes 25.0. Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, I think I need to add `ON h.id_kid = w.id_kid AND YEAR(h.date_track) = YEAR(w.date_track) AND MONTH(h.date_track) = MONTH(w.date_track)` and `GROUP BY YEAR(h.date_track), MONTH(h.date_track)` to the group statement, else months could get mixed-up between years whenever I have more records from multiple years (?)

Comment: Yes, you need to add a year as well while joining and group by for multiple years and months.

About this, "integers numbers remained without decimals after applying ROUND(AVG(), 1)... but on your proposed solution, 25 becomes 25.0. Any ideas why?" I thought, UNION is doing that but I executed your individual query and even that gives no decimal point. No, I don't have any idea why there is different behavior of the same function in different queries.